# Cannot access 'ChatClientePageModule' before initialization Ionic 5

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

After performing the merge, the list-client.component.ts page screen does not access when clicking the button

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5s5Eo.png

My chat-cliente.module.ts:

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { ImagePicker } from '@ionic-native/image-picker';


import { ChatClientePage } from './chat-cliente.page';
import { ListaClientePageComponent } from './lista-cliente.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'lista',
  },
  {
    path: 'chat/:id',
    component: ChatClientePage
  },
  {
    path: 'lista',
    component: ListaClientePageComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes),
  ],
  declarations: [
    ChatClientePage,
    ListaClientePageComponent
  ],
  providers: [
    ImagePicker
  ]
})
export class ChatClientePageModule {}
```

Comment: Welcome, @Jean Will. Please provide more details to it if you want to draw other contributors attention. Cheers